# is_singular just won't work

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm working with wp 3.9.1 and plugin Custom Content Type Manager. I'm creating my own theme. I created a custom type called "aggregato". I also use custom taxonomies. I then created a WP_query for my front-page:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => array ('post', 'aggregato'),
   'cat' => '-1',
   'posts_per_page' => 12,
));
```

The query works, it returns 12 items of both the "post" and "aggregato" post types. Problem is that I want to format them differently. So when I use:

```
if ( is_singular('aggregato') ) {
    //my code
}
```

Nothing happens. It never enters, that condition is never return true. I don't know what to do anymore. I used `is_singular()`, `is_single()`, `$query->post-type`, `$post->post-type`. Nothing. It just does not work.

Anybody has any idea? Any pointers? Please, help!

EDIT: the point is that using the codex and looking for answetrs on the web I was always sent to that particular function. It got some time to understand that it was not my case. I think that the question I posted was very clear. I was just, very simply, wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you need different stying on the frontpage, or on a single page, ie single.php

Comment: Please post the entire code where you are calling `is_singular()` so we can see the context.

Comment: As said elsewhere, I was wrongly using it inside a loop with multiple results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are trying to check post type inside the Loop. To check the post type, try this:

```
global $post;
if('post' == $post->post_type ){
  // post stuff here
}
else{
  // aggregato stuff here
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `get_post_type()` function to get post type of current post.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the `is_singular()` condition. The first line of it's codex states

> This conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed

The key word there is *displayed*. It will only return true if the page that the user is currently looking at, is a single instance of the provided post type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to loop through the posts returned by the query? You create a loop from the query like so:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Content for single post here
    }
}
```